# Xcode 4.5 ios6 button open new view in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios

I know how I can get a button to open a new ViewController(new class) in the storyboard by dragging and dropping. But I need a code that I can write in the .m file that opens a new View when my button is clicked.

In my FirstViewController.m i got:

```
- (IBAction)button1:(id)sender {

}
```

What code do i need in this to get the button to open the SecondViewController?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"TheSequeName" sender: self];
```

The @"TheSequeName" is defined when you ctrl drag a button to open a new view controller on the storyboard

If you don't use segue, there are many variants to open a new view controller. The basic one is using a separate NIB (without storyboard)

```
SecondViewController *view = [[SecondViewController allow] initWithNibName:@"NibName" bundle:nil];
```

If you declare your view controller on Storyboard, you can use

```
SecondViewController *view = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewStoryboardId"];
```

Then you show your SecondViewController using navigation controller

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
```

Or as modal view

```
[self presentModalViewController:view animated:YES];
```

Comment: But I Do Not want to drag and drop button to new view in storyboard! I just want a code so I dont need to do anything in the storyboard

Comment: Just updated the answer. If the second view is already on the storyboard, you can use SecondViewController *view = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewStoryboardId"];

Comment: Thanks, that was the answer I was looking for!

Comment: @user1734802 If you are happy with the answer, you should accept the solution. Click on the "white" tick (check mark) beside this answer. Cheers. Vito